# What words or concepts describe how something feels like/ is experienced like for the first time?

Tags: adjectives, compound-adjectives

I can’t explain myself better than this, but I’m looking for something that describes a first impression, the experience of doing something new for the first time, specially something meaningful. For example, how you feel when you listen for the first time to your soon-to-be favorite song, or when you see a girl that you find extremely beautiful, but with a beauty that is different from all beauty you have seen.

Comment: Newfound is frequently used to describe an experience that is not just new but special. A transcendent experience may not be new but it carries the idea of going beyond the ordinary experience of things.

Answer (score 1):

nascent  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nascent) adj.

> starting to grow or develop; being born

As in:

> Los Angeles Times 2019  “He did this for many artists. It was his
>   gift; a rare gift. He spotted and nurtured nascent talent and brought
>   to their work a layered intelligence rooted in acute observation.”

**nascent** describes the birth or beginning of something, like a new experience, a trend, an idea, or an action.

[Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=nascent)

> From 1620s, "in the act of being born;" 1706 in the figurative sense
>   of "beginning to exist or grow, coming into being,"